# Low accuracy and WARNING: WARNING:tensorflow: Model was constructed with shape? What should I want to change

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm doing a recurrent neural network with Keras. My data frame consists of 22 features(x) and y is 0 and 1(binary).
Below is my code and it gets consistent low accuracy with epoch 10 too. Also, it's giving me a **shape error**. I don't know how to improve this. Could anyone help me to understand the shape it asking? It's really confusing which kind of shapes it need to give for input and hidden layers???

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Flatten
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
import numpy as np
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

#Pandas dataframe csv
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, 22].values

# split into 67% for train and 33% for test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=seed)

#Check the shapes
print(X_train.shape)
y_train.shape
(590217, 22)
(590217,)

#Reshape it and check the shape
x_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 1, 22)
x_test  = X_test.reshape(-1, 1, 22)
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
(590217, 1, 22)
(290704, 1, 22)


# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, activation='relu', input_shape=(25, 22),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=10)

Epoch 1/3
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 25, 22) for input Tensor("lstm_6_input:0", shape=(None, 25, 22), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 22).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 25, 22) for input Tensor("lstm_6_input:0", shape=(None, 25, 22), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 22).
59022/59022 [==============================] - 337s 6ms/step - loss: 0.1966 - accuracy: 0.1096
Epoch 2/3
59022/59022 [==============================] - 310s 5ms/step - loss: 0.1841 - accuracy: 0.1584
Epoch 3/3
59022/59022 [==============================] - 294s 5ms/step - loss: 0.1823 - accuracy: 0.1721
```

#I increase the epochs and check the accuracy but it didn't get improve what else should I need to change

Comment: you need to pass input_shape=(1, 22) in the first LSTM layer

Answer (score 1):

In the first layer of the model you put input_shape=(25, 22) but you are trying to fit it into a dataset with the shape (1, 22).
To improve the accuracy, try shuffling the data before fitting it into the model.

```
import random
np.random.shuffle(x_train)
np.random.shuffle(y_train)
```

You can also try **binary_crossentropy** for the loss function instead of MSE as it is specifically for two class problems.